# How to use nodemon with express js while npm start?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, nodemon

I want to use **nodemon** to automatically detect changes in my scripts in node.js project and restart when change detected. I have my project setup using **express.js**. How to use nodemon with express.js, so that when i type `npm start`, nodemon initiates itself.

Answer (score 9):

Install nodemon as globally first, using these commands

```
`npm install -g nodemon` or `sudo npm install -g nodemon`
```

Next, ensure the "scripts" field of package.json file as this type

```
"scripts": {
    "start":"nodemon index.js",
    "devStart": "nodemon index.js"
}
```

If not as this type then change it and run
`npm run devStart`

Answer (score 6):

For this firstly install nodemon globally as

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Now go to your express.js project directory and in that open the **package.json** file. In the package.json file change
`"start": "node ./bin/www"` to `"start": "nodemon ./bin/www"`

Now run your app using `npm start`

Comment: Why question and answer yourself ?

Comment: You don't need `-g` for this. Just use `npm install -S nodemon`

Answer (score 3):

Install what you need:

```
npm install express nodemon
```

Ensure to set up express, server and others properly:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
...
```

Add `"start": "nodemon index.js"`, to the "scripts" in your `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "nodemon index.js",
},
```

Run `npm start` on your terminal.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to install nodemon, so give root privilege and install globally using following command:

```
sudo npm install nodemon -g
```

Then, go to your node project directory and open package.json and change "node" to "nodemon" in start field of scripts field.Ex:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:
after install nodemon just run your app with `nodemon start` .

Answer (score 1):

first of all, install Nodemon

```
npm i nodemon
```

after this, go to package.json and add a new key/value into scripts,
like this

```
  "scripts": {
       "dev": "nodemon src/index.js"
      },
```

so now just start you app with `npm run dev`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `npm install nodemon` or `npm install -g nodemon` and then `nodemon .\[your-app-name].js`. Remember for each time you make any changes to your code press `Ctrl + S` to save the changes so `nodemon` can recognize changes and apply them. To SumUp There is two steps to use nodemne:

```
//step #1
npm install (-g) nodemon
//step #2
nodemon .\[your-app-name].js
```