# Tailwind css not auto rendering on react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using tailwind css to apply styling to my react project but the issue I have is whenever I apply any css class, I have to kill my dev server and retart the dev server for the css changes to appear. I followed all the procedures to install tailwind css using npm. I need a solution to this problem so that the changes appear as I save it.

Comment: Do you add the paths to all of your template files in your tailwind.config.js file [https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app)

Comment: @pylwalker Yes this is the tailwind.config.js
        module.exports = {
           content: [
              "./src/**/*.{html, js}",
              ],
            theme: {
                extend: {},
            },
           plugins: [],
            }

Answer (score 1):

You can use npm package called `nodemon` which automatically restarts the server whenever the changes are encountered.

For the installation use this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

To integrate `nodemon` with your project follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45544726/13431819) link.